# How to call local api using curl in laravel?

Tags: laravel

Using **laravel api** in local API fetch and display data in the view file:

```
$url = 'http://demo.local:8000/api/category12';
           $ch = curl_init();
           curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
           curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, false);
           curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
           curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
            'Content-Type: application/json'
          ]);
    
           $response = curl_exec ($ch);
           $err = curl_error($ch);  //if you need
          curl_close ($ch);
          return $response;
```

Comment: welocome to SO ..what error u r getting ?

Comment: you need to add a route and do this (at least) in a method of the controller you connect to that route. Or in the route itself. Have you read laravel docs?

Answer (score 0):

If it's a local API, you can treat your controller as a [Real Time Facade](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/facades#real-time-facades)

> Using real-time facades, you may treat any class in your application
> as if it were a facade.

For example, let's assume our CategoryController controller has a detail method:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\Category;

class CategoryController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * return the category object for the given id.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return response
     */
    public function detail($id)
    {
        return response()->json(['data' => Category::findOrFail($id)]);
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like :

```
use Facades\App\Http\Controllers\CategoryController;
$category = CategoryController::detail(5);
```

> When the real-time facade is used, the CategoryController
> implementation will be resolved out of the service container using the
> class name that appears after the Facades prefix

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    $hit = "http://demo.local:8000/api/category12";
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_URL => $hit,
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'http://YOUR-DOMAIN'
    ));
    $resp = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    return $resp;
```